HVAC condensor fan issue
When i turn my thermostat to cool on auto, both fan and compressor kick on. After several hrs both quit and inside unit stays on and no cold air?

How long does it stay on?  Is there cold air when working?

it is normal for fan to stay on for 15-30 minutes AFTER the compressor has stoped.

Usually the unit works fine for a couple of days. Nice cool air. Runs for about 10 to 15 minutes to achieve the desired temp and shuts off like it's  supposed to and the house is quiet. Then there's times when the condenser fan and compressor shut off and the blower motor keeps running and thus blows warm air. Once I notice it, I turn off the unit via thermostat. I have felt the fan motor and it's not hot. Not sure what's causing this or why the furnace blower stays on.
